Azure Application Insights with NestJS not logging requests
I'm trying to get Azure AppInsights to log incoming requests when using NestJS. Currently using package: "applicationinsights": "2.7.3" and node 16, deployed via App Service on a Linux machine.
Main.ts configuration is as such:
import * as azureAppInsights from 'applicationinsights';

... 
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { bufferLogs: true });
  
  azureAppInsights
      .setup(process.env.APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING)
      .setAutoDependencyCorrelation(false)
      .setAutoCollectRequests(true)
      .setAutoCollectPerformance(true, true)
      .setAutoCollectExceptions(true)
      .setAutoCollectDependencies(true)
      .setAutoCollectConsole(true, true)
      .setUseDiskRetryCaching(true)
      .setSendLiveMetrics(true)
      .setDistributedTracingMode(azureAppInsights.DistributedTracingModes.AI_AND_W3C)
      .start();

  await app.listen(normalizePort(process.env.PORT || 3000));


For some reason, I do not get the incoming requests traced, however I do get dependency requests traced. What am I missing?

"Can you please specify the Node version of your app

Where you are checking the  traces ?Are you checking locally or for deployed app? How you are deploying your app ?

Hello, I've added them now:

node 16
App Service on Linux machine
checking them online via AppInsights > Transaction search


Before await app.Listen add this line of code  app.use(azureAppInsights.defaultClient.middleware); and check the logs

I can't seem to find a middleware property on the defaultClient. Am I supposed to have some sort of appInsights package for NestJS? The weird bit is that the dependencies are tracked and visibile. And even other traces, if I do them explicitly, it's just that the setAutoCollectRequests doesn't handle NestJS's incoming requests.

With your code Iam able to see traces,exception and custom events..but not requests.Trying from my end.Will let you know.

Meanwhile Refer this blog 1 and 2 once

In the meantime, I might have figured it out. It seems to work ok if I swap the order, and initialize Nest app after start AppInsights. I'm still investigating, but seems to be that way.

Change the order of import packages.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Yes, the issue seems to be with the order of the import packages and the initialization of NestJS App(NestFactory ).

First initialize the Application Insights and then the Nest App.
I am able to trace requests with the below order.

import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import * as azureAppInsights from 'applicationinsights';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

dotenv.config();

azureAppInsights
.setup(process.env.APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING)
.setAutoDependencyCorrelation(true)
.setAutoCollectRequests(true)
.setAutoCollectPerformance(true, true)
.setAutoCollectExceptions(true)
.setAutoCollectDependencies(true)
.setAutoCollectConsole(true, true)
.setUseDiskRetryCaching(true)
.setSendLiveMetrics(true)
.setDistributedTracingMode(azureAppInsights.DistributedTracingModes.AI_AND_W3C)
.start();

async function bootstrap() {
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { bufferLogs: true });

console.log('Application Insights Connection String:', process.env.APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING);

await app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
}
bootstrap();

Requests:

Exception & Trace:

